# Análisis de datos selectivos en Pandas

Tags: python, lista, pandas, dataframe

Estoy trabajando con Pandas.
Tengo una multilista similar a la siguiente, formada por varias listas, cada una con 3 índices: Device, Time y Value:

```
lista:
    [['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:45', 401.0],
     ['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:40', 449.0],
     ['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:35', 560.0],
     ['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:30', 1800.0],
     ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:50', 420.0],
     ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:45', 1900.0],
     ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:40', 2000.0],
     ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:35', 2300.0]]
```

Necesito determinar para cada Device, si el Value estuvo entre 400 y 450 almenos el 50% de las veces y que me lo reporte, es decir, basándome en el ejemplo de arriba, esperaría obtener una respuesta como:

```
Device air10058840: sí
Device air10145931: no
```

Ya intenté conseguir esto usando dataframes, haciendo bucles múltiples que analicen 2 listas a la vez y las compare, pero no consigo el resultado y de todos modos si lo consiguiera creo que me estoy complicando mucho, si a alguno se le ocurre una idea más simple para que pueda probar se lo agradecería!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una pregunta muy interesante.

Un posible diseño sería:

- Identificar los dispositivos distintos.
- Crear una función que evalúa los valores de cada dispositivo según tus criterios.
- Aislar los valores de la tabla de cada dispositivo individual, y el evaluarlos según aquella función.

En vez de explicarlo todo, anoto la programación con comentarios abajo.

```
lista = [['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:45', 401.0],
     ['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:40', 449.0],
     ['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:35', 560.0],
     ['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:30', 1800.0],
     ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:50', 420.0],
     ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:45', 1900.0],
     ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:40', 2000.0],
     ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:35', 2300.0]]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(lista)

# Definir una lista de dispositivos posibles
devices = list(set(df[0]))

#Esta función determina si el 50% de los valores de una matriz/array cae entre el rango.
def evaluarRango(a):
 n = len(a)
 valores_entre_rango = len( [i for i in a if (i >= 400) and (i <= 450)] )
 if valores_entre_rango/n >= 0.50:
  return True
 else:
  return False

# Iterar a través de los dispositivos distintos
for device in devices:
 # Aislamos la tercera columna df[2] de la tabla que contengan este dispositivo, que por su vez aislamos con df[df[0] == device]
 valores = df[df[0] == device][2].to_list()
 # Usamos la función evaluarRango() definida arriba para la evaluación de este conjunto de valores.
 if evaluarRango(valores):
  print("Device " + device + ": sí" )
 else:
  print("Device " + device + ": no")
```

Sería útil estudiar los usos de la función de pandas que se llama apply() y también funciones de la lambda.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Facilitan el análisis de tablas complicadas.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

listas = [['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:45', 401.0],
          ['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:40', 449.0],
          ['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:35', 560.0],
          ['air10058840', '3/5/2022 15:30', 1800.0],
          ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:50', 420.0],
          ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:45', 1900.0],
          ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:40', 2000.0],
          ['air10145931', '3/5/2022 15:35', 2300.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(listas, columns=["device", "time", "value"])

def group_modifier(group):
    # Obtenemos la cantidad de registros del grupo
    casos_totales = group.shape[0]
    # Obtenemos la cantidad de registros del grupo cuyo value está entre 400 y 450
    casos = group[(group.value >= 400) & (group.value <= 450)].shape[0]

    return (casos / casos_totales) >= 0.5

resultado = df.groupby("device").apply(group_modifier)

print(resultado)
```

La idea es agrupar el DataFrame por device y aplicar la función group_modifier a cada grupo. Dentro de dicha función obtenemos la cantidad de casos totales y la cantidad de casos que cumplen la condición. Luego, vemos si la división entre casos y casos totales (que es un numero que siempre estará entre 0 y 1 y nos dará un porcentaje pero dividido por 100) es mayor o igual a 0.5, o 50 %.

Esto resulta en una serie cuyo indice es el device y está compuesta por trues y falses.

Puedes acceder a un caso especifico usando `resultado[resultado.index == eldevice]` o iterar sobre todos los casos usando `for device, estado in resultado.items()`. resultado.items() devuelve un iterador en el cual puedes iterar e ir obteniendo una tupla de estilo (indice, valor). En este caso, esa tupla sería (device, estado).

Esto produce:

```
device
air10058840     True
air10145931    False
dtype: bool
```

Referencias:

- [pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)
- [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- [pandas.Series.items](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html)